# Android VideoView, seamless playback during orientation change

Tags: android, buffering, android-videoview

I'm using a VideoView to play a mp4 file in my application. Is there a way to save all the content that was buffered so when the orientation of the screen is changed the user doesn't have to wait another 10 seconds or more for the video to start playing again.

Perhaps "saving the buffered video" isn't the right solution, I'm just looking for a way to have the playback almost appear seamless when the orientation of the screen is changed.

I'm already saving the video positioning and using the "seekTo" method to start the video where it left off. But I'm looking to prevent the rebuffering as well.  I searched all over stackoverflow and couldn't find any discussions on this.

Thanks!

Bradley4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could handle the configuration change yourself so that the application isn't restarted.

Another solution might be to put the VideoView into a Fragment. Then rather than killing the Fragment with the Activity, you might just pause the video detach the Fragment and re-attach after the configuration change. Although now that I think about it, I think the Fragment may also be re-created on the configuration change...

Very interested in how you solve this, please post your solution if no one answers.

Comment: Thanks Spidy,  I took your first suggestion and this worked well.  I added android:configChanges="orientation" attribute to the particular activity in the manifest.  (ie) <activity android:name=".Act_ItemDetail"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="orientation"> 
        </activity>

Comment: if i change the size of a layout in which videoview is present,  the video is in prepared state the video view is distorted and not coming to proper position.

Comment: Have you called invalidate() and requestLayout()?